# Challenges in Configuring terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am trying to get the backend.tf created for all sub-folders included in the current project.
I have installed terragrunt on my local system

```
   $ which terragrunt
   /usr/local/bin/terragrunt
   $ terragrunt -version
   terragrunt version v0.28.18
```

Here is my terragrunt.hcl from my parent folder

```
 $ cat  /user_folder/user-x/terragrunt.hcl
remote_state {
  backend  = "gcs"
  generate = {
    path = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  config = {
    bucket  = "terraform-bucket"
    prefix = "${path_relative_to_include()}/user_folder/user-x/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

In my sub-folder /user_folder/user-x/permissions/, I have terragrunt.hcl

```
$ cat  /user_folder/user-x/permissions/terragrunt.hcl
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

Also I have exported `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the appropriate JSON.

Now when I execute

```
$ terragrunt plan --terragrunt-log-level debug --terragrunt-debug
                                                                                                    DEBU[0000] Did not find any locals block: skipping evaluation.
DEBU[0000] Running command: terraform --version          prefix=[/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x]
DEBU[0000] Terraform version: 0.13.5
DEBU[0000] Reading Terragrunt config file at /mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/terragrunt.hcl
DEBU[0000] Did not find any locals block: skipping evaluation.
DEBU[0000] The file path /mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/backend.tf already exists, but was a previously generated file by terragrunt. Since if_exists for code generation is set to "overwrite_terragrunt", regenerating file.
DEBU[0000] Generated file /mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/backend.tf.
INFO[0000] Debug mode requested: generating debug file terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json in working dir /mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x
DEBU[0000] The following variables were detected in the terraform module:
DEBU[0000] [project_name project_owner contact_group project_expiration organization_id location billing_account_id vpc_project_id folder_id gcs_location sa_role shared_vpcs]
DEBU[0000] Variables passed to terraform are located in "/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json"
DEBU[0000] Run this command to replicate how terraform was invoked:
DEBU[0000]      terraform plan -var-file="/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/terragrunt-debug.tfvars.json" "/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/"
DEBU[0002] Initializing remote state for the gcs backend  prefix=[/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/]
DEBU[0003] Remote state GCS bucket terraform-bucket does not exist. Attempting to create it  prefix=[/mylocalpc/git_test_repo/user-x/]
ERRO[0003] Missing required GCS remote state configuration project
ERRO[0003] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

And the GCS bucket terraform-bucket does exists.
Unsure what I'm missing here... looking for kind help

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Because of this:

```
  ERRO[0003] Missing required GCS remote state configuration project
```

I think you need to run these before you run terragrunt?

```
  gcloud config set project <your project>
  gcloud auth application-default login
```

Comment: doesn't help in my case...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the cloud storage created. So had to specify `skip_bucket_creation` to `true`. Check out [terragrunt doc](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-remote-state-configuration-dry/) for details (search for `skip_bucket_creation`).

```
remote_state {
  backend = "gcs"  
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  config = {
    bucket  = "some-bucket"
    prefix  = "some-prefix"
    skip_bucket_creation = true
  }
}
```